# PHP object mapping best way

Tags: php, json, api

Creating Rest API I'm has accoutred with problem.

Our client given us request, that he want to send for us:

json example:

```
    {
    "request": {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Snow",
        "age": "19"
    }
}
```

My User model class looks like:

```
class User
{
    public $firstName;

    public $latName;

    public $age;
}
```

What is best way to set object from given json ? Using some existing libraries or write custom mapper ?

I'm not interested on inventing bicycle.

Comment: Even using ready libraries require to create attributes mapper.
You have to answer it yourself if the library overhead is a good idea for your project.

Comment: Good question. Poor answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally go with:

```
class User
{
    public static function fromArray($array)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->firstName = $array['name'];
        ...
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Then instantiating with:

```
$user = User::fromArray($responseFromWhatever);
```

Comment: Or using stdClass instead of array. Plus I would throw error whether one of the fields is missing, or there is an extra field, which is not in the model.